# How to decrese the possibility of the producer acquiring the lock whereas the consumer could not get the lock when using std::condition_variable?

Tags: c++, c++11, conditional-statements, mutex, race-condition

How can I decrease the possibility of the producer(i.e. main thread in the code snippet code below) acquiring the lock whereas the consumer(i.e. wait thread) could not get the lock? It is would be better if you could tell me a method to avoid it. I don't think it is a good idea to use `std::thread::sleep_for` or `std::thread::yield`. And I have done some test and found that there is no effect when using `std::thread::yield`.

I have thought about it for a long time, I would be grateful to have some help with this question.

If you run the code snippet, you may see such output:

```
Waiting... 
test 
Notifying falsely... 
Notifying true change... 
Notifying true change... 
Notifying true change... 
Notifying true change... 
Notifying true change... 
Notifying true change...
(**many many such output**)
Notifying true change... 
test 
...finished waiting. i == 1
```

Here is the related code snippet(check https://godbolt.org/z/9dwDJN, quoted from en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/notify_one ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m;
int i = 0;
bool done = false;

void waits()
{
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    std::cout << "Waiting... \n";
    cv.wait(lk, []{std::cout<<"test"<<std::endl; return i == 1;});
    std::cout << "...finished waiting. i == 1\n";
    done = true;
}

void signals()
{
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    std::cout << "Notifying falsely...\n";
    cv.notify_one(); // waiting thread is notified with i == 0. 
    // cv.wait wakes up, checks i, and goes back to waiting 

    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
    i = 1;
    while (!done)
    {
        std::cout << "Notifying true change...\n";
        lk.unlock();
        cv.notify_one(); // waiting thread is notified with i == 1, cv.wait returns 
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));   // I don't think it is good method.
        //std::this_thread::yield();  //Maybe, this does not work.
        lk.lock();
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t1(waits), t2(signals);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Comment: Your problem is caused by the spinning (`while` loop). Even if you change `done` to be atomic, which allows you to avoid locking in the loop, even then, the output didn't change. Alternatively, you can use the condition variable to idle-wait for `done` to be set, the example is right here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable.

Comment: @DanielLangr, OK, I've deleted my answer. Now I'm lost: even spinning the while loop shouldn't produce the *Notifying true change...* multiple times before the last *test* line.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Why not? You are spinning and the message is printed out in each iteration. It will be printed until the signaling thread will notify the change of `done`, which simply does not take place immediately. Note that `notify_one` does not block until the waiting thread gets notified. It simply returns, whether or not the waiting threads gets really notified.

Comment: @DanielLangr, the signalling thread notifies one waiter. The waiting thread gets the mutex ownership as being the only thread waiting. The "test" line shall be output before the signalling thread would get the ownership on the lock, so there shall not be multiple "Notifying true change..."

Comment: @John, it doesn't actually answer your question.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov But the signaling takes some time. The waiting thread needs to be waked by some operating system mechanism (such as sending a signal) and this takes some time. Moreover, waiting threads needs to read `i`, which involves cache-coherency issues among multiple cores. Then, it writes `done`, and again, it takes some time until signaling thread "sees" this change propagated among core caches. During all this time, the loop spins. There is nothing that would block it.

Comment: @DanielLangr, it reads `i` under the lock, so that prevents the signal thread spinning. What really surprises me is that the signalling thread may cause the ABA problem, and the waiter may never see the `i` change.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Yes, but until the waiting threads gets that lock, the loop in the signaling thread can iterate 1000 times. And yes, it's prone to ABA problem.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov Here is a live demo of the ABA problem: https://godbolt.org/z/8z6WWO. `i` is first changes to 1, then the waiting thread is notified, and then `i` is changes back to 0. The waiting thread very likely does not read 1 and runs forever.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov & Daniel Langr Is there some good method to avoid or resolve ABA problem? Could you suggest some related documents for me to go through?

Comment: @John I don't think there is any single generic solution of ABA problems. You would need to specify more details and show the code that can cause it. In your question, there is no ABA problem, since `done` is only changed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wait for `done` completely without a lock, if you make it an *atomic* variable. This would even make much more sense to me in this case than using a mutex. However, this does not change the whole concept of *busy waiting*, that is, spinning in a loop until `done` is set.

Alternatively, you can wait for `done` to be set without blocking a CPU core. Simply use the same concept of condition variables. You can even use the same condition variable that was used for synchronization of `i`. The demo of this approach is here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable.

The question is which of these two solutions is "better". I would likely prefer the first spin-based solution, since one can expect, that the waiting will be very short (if the system is not oversubscribed etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I almost understand what you mean. I have read the document aforementioned by you. I understand how to implement it now. But I still have a question, what do you mean by "Alternatively, you can wait for done to be set without **blocking a CPU core**. "?  Do you mean to avoid the CPU core been occupied by busy waiting?  Is it a clerical error? We usually think something is idle if it has been blocked. I am not a native speaker.Maybe, it's just my misunderstanding.

Comment: @John Yes, exactly, I meant to avoid the CPU core being occupied by busy waiting.

Comment: @ Daniel Langr Thank you for the clarification. Is there a term for "ABA problem"? Do you have dug deep in it? Could you please suggest some related documents for me to go through?

Comment: @John As for ABA problem, read my comment below the question. As for some documents, I don't know any specific. I could use Google, but you can use it as well. Generally, about multihreading in C++, I would recommend the _C++ Concurrency in Action_ book.

Comment: Quote from your comment[emphasis mine]: Here is a live demo of the ABA problem: godbolt.org/z/8z6WWO. **The waiting thread very likely does not read 1 and runs forever. ** I fully understand what you mean and the code snippet. But how can I solve this ABA question? The method you aforementioned(i.e. en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable. ) is a way to slove it indeed. But it not suitable under some conditions, e.g. reading data from a peripheral device(the producer waiting for the consumer may cause some data lost).

Comment: @john To avoid data loss in such a case, buffer data into some queue. Anyway, again, I think there is no generic solution. You would need to provide a particular ABA problem you need to resolve. In my exemplary solution, you may, for instance, use a second variable (mutex-protected) to track the number of updates.

Answer (score 0):

Why you think is a bad ideea to use sleep?
Its pretty standard to use std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100)); in while(true) threads and it will also fix your problem.